# Alter the path of the more link from Views

Tags: views, 8

In Drupal 8 how do I alter the *more* link?

I need to give it a path which is based on a taxonomy id that is based on the current path (where the view is on) which has the taxonomy name in the path.

The current page also has a field which has this taxonomy name as a result. (but changes per page)

--

I'm trying to retrieve the taxonomy ID based on the taxonomy that is placed on the node and give the id to the more link

I am not sure if this is clear. But I have a views page with filters. And the taxonomies are the filters. Certain pages (theme pages) have their own taxonomy directed to it with a views block. The more link of that block links to the views page, I want the link to automatically check the filters of the taxonomy that is being used on these theme pages.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question, I have been needing the same thing.
I solved it by means of:

1) add the field 'link to taxonomy term' and exclude it from visualization

2) format the description field as 'clipped version' (I am using right now a Spanish version of Drupal 8, not sure what the English option name is called)

3) rewrite the output for the description field as '{{ description__format }} {{ view_taxonomy_term }}'

That did the trick.

I hope that that's what you had asked, and that someone can take advantage of it.

*EDIT*: After re-reading your question, I realize that what I was trying to solve is different: a taxonomy terms view, which returns a list of terms, the description shortened to 160 chars, with a 'read more' link based in the taxonomy term's custom path (/path instead of /taxonomy/term/2).

Since I haven't been able to find an online answer to that, and given that google drove me to this question while trying to find an answer to mine, I think I could still leave this answer here. However, if the OP or some mod tell me to remove this answer, I gladly will.